# "stars on heaven" vs "stars in heaven"

Tags: word-choice, prepositions, expressions

Which expression is correct?

> stars **in** heaven

or

> stars **on** heaven

I want to express that something comes in really, really large numbers. For instance: "*There are more Blabla than stars on/in heaven*".

Comment: I'd say "in" is better than "on".

Comment: I'd say "the sky" is better than "heaven". I'd also say this is a rather nice question for [English language learners](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/41665/english-language-learners?referrer=NIy3I1OlXZ2EgMrV1X1RuQ2), but too basic for any native speaker.

Comment: @RegDwighт: Thanks for the link, I wasn't aware of that site. I guess my questions (not only this one) rather fit there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In dialogue, “stars on heaven” might be used to imply the speaker is non-native.  “Stars in Heaven” (or the “stars in the heavens” mentioned in a later answer) is a rather  more natural form than “stars on heaven”, but “stars in the sky” is probably heard much more commonly than either.

Answer (score 4):

This [Ngram](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=stars+in+heaven%2C+stars+on+heaven&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=0&smoothing=3&share=) makes it very clear that 'stars on heaven' isn't used - it gets no hits at all.

This is because the concept of heaven is a space that surrounds the stars, so they are *in* heaven in the same way that an aircraft is *in* the air, rather than the tangible item that would be required for them to be *on*, as when an aircraft is *on* the solid ground.

Comment: And to be honest, it does look like a typo.

Comment: I would be very wary of putting forward explanations for particular choices of preposition in English or any other language. They work up to a point, but there is often an inexplicable arbitraryness about them.

Answer (score 2):

"In" is the only preposition that works in idiomatic English in this case. Sometimes it's possible to choose between two or three prepositions, but the stars are metaphorically **in Heaven** and the people are here **on Earth**.

Answer (score 2):

As a minor exception, if using 'heaven' to refer to the sphere of fixed stars in the [Ptolemaic Model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geocentric_model#Ptolemaic_Model) (or other similar cosmologies), on would be the correct word choice.  This is because in this context heaven is referring to an actual surface.  If you're doing that the context needs to be made explicit to avoid confusion.  Otherwise I agree with the other answers that 'in' is the correct choice.

Answer (score 1):

Use *stars in the heavens* where *the heavens* means *the sky*.